# Magento Catalog Price Rule Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I'm trying to enable the price rules on my product. I need a discount on all my catalogue.
So I create a rule not touching condition to include all product. I set all following a guide, so I don't think to have made something wrong but the rule don't apply to the catalog.
Tables catalogrule are all empty
 Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the rule and activated it. Verifying shows that this rule does not change price for desired group of products.

One more reason of rule inefficiency is that you have not applied it. If you have just created Magento catalog price rules or implemented some modifications, apply them pressing correspondingly Apply Rules button on the toolbar.

Review attached image for more clarification.

[image: magento catalog price rules]

Comment: I've applied them and reindexed all catalog and deleted cache. I noticed that all catalogrule tables are empty. Only catalogrule and catalogrule_customer_group are populated

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I write for othern that need it. 
I had loaded demo contents in my store and there was also price rules. The catalogrule table had ID = 11 for my rule. 
I need to reset the autoincrement to 1 and it start to work! 
So remove all rules and execute this query to the SQL DB

```
ALTER TABLE `catalogrule`AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Then create again the rule and apply it! It will work!